# Angular: Iterate over ngForm controls?

Tags: angular

The goal is when a user clicks a button to go to the next page, prevent the user from continuing and display an error indicator if the page is partially filled out but not valid.

In a template-driven form, I have several container elements using the `NgModelGroup` attribute to represent a "page" in the form. In my component I want to reference this collection so I can access them with an index. Since I couldn't get this collection (@AJT_82 comments why below), this was my approach:

I made a class to hold info about a page.

```
export class Page
{
    title: string;
    hasError: boolean;  //should the page display an error indicator
}
```

and in my component I populate an array, `pages: Page[]`, in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.pages = [{title: "Page 1", hasError: false},
                  {title: "Page 2", hasError: false},
                  {title: "Page 3", hasError: false}]
}
```

and @DeborahK in her answer gave me

```
this.form.form.get('pg1'))
```

to get the individual `ngModelGroup` named 'pg' + currentPg+1 (+1 to match the View since arrays starts at 0) that I could then use in a click event that will result in either A)going to the next page or B)setting the `hasError` property to true and not going to next page.

```
let p = this.form.form.get("pg"+ (this.currentPg+1));
//if the page is partially filled out but not valid
if(p.invalid && p.dirty)
  this.pages[this.currentPg].hasError = true;
else
{
  //even if it's false, re-false it ;)
  this.pages[this.currentPg].hasError = false;

  //continue to next page. 
  //i.e. this.currentPg++ or this.currentPg--
}
```

Back in the template, to show an error indicator on either the tab or the page I just check the `pages[currentPg].hasError` property. Assign "has-error" class on tab element for styling the tab.

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <a *ngFor="let p of pages" 
     [ngClass]="(p.hasError ? ' has-error' : '')"><p>{{p.title}}</p></a>
</div>

<form #f="ngForm">
  <div ngModelGroup="pg1"> <!-- pages[0] -->
    <div id="errorBlock" *ngIf="pages[currentPg].hasError">
      You had an error.
    </div>
    <div>
      <input ngModel/>
      <input ngModel/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input ngModel/>
      <input ngModel/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ngModelGroup="pg2"> <!-- pages[1] -->
    <input ngModel/>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here's the example's component:

```typescript
...
currentPg: number = 0;
pages: Page[] = [];
@ViewChild('f') public form: NgForm;

ngOnInit()
{
    this.pages = [{title: "Page 1", hasError: false},
                  {title: "Page 2", hasError: false},
                  {title: "Page 3", hasError: false}]
}

NextPage()
{
  let p = this.form.form.get("pg"+ (this.currentPg+1));
  //if the page is partially filled out but not valid
  if(p.invalid && p.dirty)
    this.pages[this.currentPg].hasError = true;
  else
  {
    //even if it's false, re-false it ;)
    this.pages[this.currentPg].hasError = false;

    //Do navigation logic. 
    //i.e. this.currentPg++ or this.currentPg--
  }
}
```

Again, a lot of this can go away if there's a way to get the collection of ngModelGroups and use it like an array.

Comment: what is `@ViewChild('f') `? what is `this.tabs`?

Comment: you have not attached a reference to the form an you are using view child

Comment: *but you can see what I'm trying to achieve*: no, I can't. Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: First of all, your ViewChild reference is wrong. You are defining it as #form in your html but use 'f' in your ts file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the line with `this.tabs`. Also, the Viewchild reference was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Well, your form will not be ready in OnInit, so you'll have no values. I'd consider using a reactive form, which I would probably recommend anyway, unless you have a real simple form. When building the form in the TS code, you know exactly when and where the form is available, i.e know where and when to iterate the form controls.

Comment: @AJT_82  `console.log(this.form.controls);` works when placed in ngOnInit(). And the reason I was avoiding reactive forms is I built this form(very large, time consuming form) already and to rebuild it... it just seems like there'd be a way to get a collection or atleast a way to loop `this.form.controls` and assign them to an array.

Comment: Ah, right. It wasn't just ready when I tried to set the the groups in an array, then it gave me empty array at first in OnInit. At least that is how it behaves in Plunker. It did work in other life cycle hook.

Comment: I don't follow. `console.log(this.form.controls);` gives an empty array in plunker? but in another hook, say ngAfterViewInit(), it works?

Comment: No the form controls are there, but trying to make an array of the form groups give empty array. But if I put that in `ngAfterViewChecked()` it shows the array properly, but that makes no sense to put it there or any other lifecycle hook that you cannot control when is executed. One more reason for why changing to reactive form :P

Comment: I mean, you don't want the code executed randomly on change detection, right? Because `AfterViewChecked` would be fired all the time.

Comment: I see. I also tried this to bind from view to model via `<div (ngModelGroup)="pages[0]" #pg1="ngModelGroup">` but logging that returned an empty array as well.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
    Object.keys((<FormGroup>this.form.form.get('pg1')).controls).forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    });
```

But the critical issue (as per the comments below your question) is *where* this code resides. I added it as part of the submit button process.

In ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit, and ngAfterViewChecked the values of these elements were null/undefined.

If you just need to know whether the form group is valid, you can just do this:

```
    let isValid = this.form.form.get('pg1').valid;
```

Alternatively, you can use a tabbed page and show an error icon on any page with validation errors, like this:

[image]

In this example, I am using template-driven forms. Each input element on the form looks something like this:

```
        <div class="form-group" 
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (productNameVar.touched || 
                                          productNameVar.dirty || product.id !== 0) && 
                                          !productNameVar.valid }">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                    for="productNameId">Product Name</label>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control" 
                        id="productNameId" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Name (required)"
                        required
                        minlength="3"
                        [(ngModel)] = product.productName
                        name="productName"
                        #productNameVar="ngModel" />
                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(productNameVar.touched ||
                                                 productNameVar.dirty || product.id !== 0) &&
                                                 productNameVar.errors">
                    <span *ngIf="productNameVar.errors.required">
                        Product name is required.
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="productNameVar.errors.minlength">
                        Product name must be at least three characters.
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can find the complete code for this example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-Final folder. (This is the code from my "Angular Routing" Pluralsight course.)

Comment: Thank you, I attempted this before but as you stated it was undefined in ngOnInit so I thought I was just doing it wrong. I could add an `initialized: boolean` and call function, `NextPage(){ if(!initialized){ initialized = true; /*Object.keys code goes here */} else {//proceed to next page} }` and that way before going to next page, you get all your controls. But, that'sn bad design. I'm really not liking that this is turning out to be a "problem: hit a wall; solution: start over" kinda deal but Reactive Forms may be the answer..

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Why do you need to get all of the control names? Are you doing something with them?

Comment: I split my form up into pages( `<div ngModelGroup><!--controls go here--></div>` ) and I can move back and forth between them, but I want to prevent the user from going to the next page if the current page is invalid ( `<button type="button" (click)="pages[currentPg].invalid ? showErrors = true : showErrors=false;Next()">` ) and for the controls that belong to that page, show their validation errors with `*ngIf="showErrors"`

Comment: You should be able to do that completely without needing to iterate through all of the controls on the form? Also, just for an alternative approach ... I used tabs to do something similar and instead of preventing moving to other tabs, I just add an error icon to the tab. I'll add a screen shot to my answer.

Comment: I'm also using tabs, but instead of displaying a single error for page, I want to display each control's validation elements that belongs inside of that page and not on any other pages. I'm switching pages with an integer so accessing a page element by index would be helpful

Comment: Cool! Yea, mine works that way as well. Any errors on the current tab are displayed under the control with the issue.

Comment: How are you referencing those elements though, do you just use template variables for every one?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant.. for each tab you check if it's valid when going to next page, then if that tab has errors you display them as well as the "!" graphic on the tab. I meant how were you doing, for example, `if(tabs[1] is invalid && is dirty) {give tabs[1] the 'has-error' class}` if `tabs` were a collection of containers(ngModelGroup), each one representing a page, and each holding a collection of inputs. I figured out a way and I'll update my original post, but I still wish I could get the collection of ngModelGroups directly.

Answer (score 3):

In `myForm.component.html`, create a reference label to the form to get access to it:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" ...>
```

Then create a button to call a function to access the form data:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" 
  (click)="getMyFormData(myForm)">
    Get Form Data
</button>
```

And in your `myForm.component.ts`

```
getMyFormData( f: NgForm ){
  Object.values(f.controls).forEach( ctl => {
    console.log(ctl);  // <-- each control is accessible here
  } );
}
```

or just the entire form data object like so:

```
getMyFormData( f: NgForm ){
  console.log(f.value) // <-- all controls accessible here
}
```